# Fetch JSON before static variables init

Tags: javascript

i'm working with some ENV value in JSON file.
In my case, i want to fetch all env variables before app start and static variables init.
I try to fetch it in index.html, but it still go after static variables. There is some way that i can do it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  fetch('config/config.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("config: ", data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
</script>
```

Thanks.

Ps: sorry about my english

Comment: Use the promise returned from `fetch` to delay your _"app start"_ logic until you have the data you need

Comment: Where is this `config.json` file? Can you import it at build time instead of fetch it at run time?

Comment: @DrewReese , in my logic, i need to fetch it in run time

Comment: @Phil i want to do it with multi lib or framework, mean it can work with reactjs or angular, vue ...

Comment: Why? It looks like a local file, i.e. you aren't fetching it from an external resource.

Answer (score 1):

well, I think you should create functions init() and start() put inside them the logic of initiation and starting the app, then call these functions from inside fetch().then().then(data=>{}).

Comment: Of course, we should do that. But in my case, i need to do it with multi languages, that mean i can run it with React Js, Angular, Vue ,...

Comment: @ĐoànTrí your case is ambiguous, and I cannot understand the reason that makes you think that you will need (React Js, Angular, Vue) together in one project, these frameworks have the same purpose, so you don't need use all of them, using one of them alone is a sufficient.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I just use one language for one project. I mean that if i use this "fetching JSON logic" in other project, other javascript language , it can work too